# How to use Visual c++ compiler to run Cmake for boost 1.39.0 building library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, cmake, windows-7-x64

I need to compile [boost 1.39.0 library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.39.0) which on this version, don't provide installer in order to run a `Visual Studio 2008` solution. The `Cmake` throw this exception.

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 9 2008
 -- The C compiler identification is unknown
 -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown

 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: 28 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

I couldn't figure out how could i specify where it could find visual studio compiler.

I'm using `boost 1.39.0` with `CMake 3.0.0`

Kind regards.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not in english

Comment: You can also set the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to point to VS2008's `cl.exe` before calling `cmake`. [See this](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F).

Comment: Thks for your help Peter but how could i do it with command line in Windows, i see that it refere to Linux for this instructions.

Comment: Open Visual Studio command prompt (Start->VisualStudio->VisualStudio Tools->...) - all the relevant environment vars will be set automatically. Run `cmake` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually build Boost with the bjam:

1. Run bootstrap.bat (it's the root directory of boost sources). This creates a bjam.exe.
2. Run bjam. Use this parameters (for 64 bit):
   *bjam toolset=msvc-9.0 --build-type=complete address-model=64 stage*

You will find all built binaries in the stage directory.
See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11597/Building-Boost-libraries-for-Visual-Studio) for more info.

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks for your help, how could i see all the warnings that bjam throw during compilation, I am concerned that this could lead to my application.